# How can I select to like wildcards in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table which has column name and having stored

```
|name|

Lebron James C. Durant
```

And I want to select and filter incomplete name. But the result is null.

```
SELECT * from partners where name LIKE "%Lebron James Durant%"
```

Here's my expected result in this query.

```
|name|

Lebron James C. Durant
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace spaces with `%` signs.

```
SELECT * from partners where name LIKE '%Lebron%James%Durant%';
```

If you want to query an arbitrary string, use like this (`@n` may be your query parameter):

```
SET @n = 'Lebron James Durant';
SELECT * from partners where name LIKE CONCAT('%', REPLACE(@n, ' ', '%'), '%')
```

Comment: tnx, it working in mysql when i do this
SELECT * from partners where name LIKE CONCAT('%', REPLACE('Lebron James Durant', ' ', '%'), '%')